# flutter kotlin dependency errors

Tags: flutter, kotlin

I am getting heaps of these errors at run time in my application, and I have been going through suggested solutions online and coming up short. Nothing seems to be working.  So, the errors:

```
e: Incompatible classes were found in dependencies. Remove them from the classpath or use '-Xskip-metadata-version-check' to suppress errors
e: C:/Users/User/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/9508325ccc4e6492ee61ca313dfda75b/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-common-1.9.0.jar!/META-INF/kotlin-stdlib-common.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.
```

And what I have tried:

This entire section was originally missing from my android\app\build.gradle file, so had to add this entire section at the very top, before plugins {}:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.9.0'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

I have tried 1.7.1 there as I think the error is suggesting, and it makes no difference, like it doesn't even recognise this setting at all.

I have tried updating all my plugins.

Not sure what else I am supposed to do with this one, I believe I have done exactly what it is asking me to do.

Answer (score 0):

In newer version of android studio when you create new flutter project the some of the `build.gradle`(android/build.gradle) code has been moved to `settings.gradle` (android/settings.gradle)

To solve the mentioned issue make changes in `setting.gradle` (android/settings.gradle)

> In plugin you will have following lines:

```
plugins {
id "dev.flutter.flutter-plugin-loader" version "1.0.0"
id "com.android.application" version "7.3.0" apply false
id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android" version "1.8.0" apply false
}
```

You might have different version for 'com.android.application' and 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' change it to version mentioned above or latest

Note: If you have added anything new in `android/build.gradle` as mentioned in question remove those changes for kotlin version