how to resolve Kotlin version issue in Flutter?
I'm doing auth0 in Flutter using the auth0_flutter package after following the readme and proper configuration(android) I got a build error that says:
e: Incompatible classes were found in dependencies. Remove them from the classpath or use '-Xskip-metadata-version-check' to suppress errors

kotlin version issue iamge
after finding the solution on the internet i reached to the point the i need to change the Kotlin version inside the android level build.gradle file inside the build block although that block was not present there and i added manually
buildscript {
repositories {
google()
mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    // Add any necessary dependencies here
}
ext.kotlin_version = '1.7.1'
}


I have played with different version of the Kotlin but still getting the same error,
i have followed the read me
https://pub.dev/packages/auth0_flutter

Remove package version in puubspec.yml file

this might help to solve the issue https://stackoverflow.com/a/78242109/20844597

buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0' // change according to your version
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version" ]
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}

subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}


Goto, android -> build.gradle ext.kotlin_version = '1.9.20'


Upgrade Kotlin Version  ext.kotlin_version = 1.9.24
android/build.gradle
In this path.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
