Kotlin version issue in new flutter projects
I have created a new project. When I add flutter_nfc_kit: then it gives the error:
Your project requires a newer version of the Kotlin Gradle plugin.  

But when I open the android level build.gradle file, it does not have the kotlin version. When I try to add kotlin latest version manually then issue does not resolve. My build.gradle after adding kotlin version is :
    buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '2.0.0' 
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:2.0.0"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

Please advice on this issue. It only appears in new projects and it always taking kotlin version 1.7.1 by default.

After flutter version 3.16, gradle plugins and kotlin version is specified in settings.gradle (inside android folder)
Hope this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/78242109/20844597

Can you share your pubspec.yaml file? What is the flutter version you are using?

nfc plugin was creating conflicts with others therefore I added it as flutter_nfc_kit:

I discovered that starting from Flutter version 3.16, some configurations that were previously in the build.gradle file have been moved to the settings.gradle file. To resolve the issue, I updated the Kotlin version from 1.7 to 2.0.0 in the settings.gradle file, and this resolved the problem.
